# Activating Vino From Command Line / VPS

Tags: vpn, vps, vino

I have signed up for VPS with tty root access. I would like to be able to access the desktop using VPN, but I'm having some trouble setting it up. What would be the best approach?

Comment: Please start with OS & release details; Ubuntu by default has no root access, so is it a Ubuntu product?  Is it Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Server? or say Ubuntu Desktop? and which release is it.

Answer (score 0):

> Seems like you have VPS with `Ubuntu Server` as your default OS. Ubuntu Server comes with `CLI` (Command line interface) so you won't be getting any UI to operate.  You can use SSH Clients and access that VPS via `terminal`.

But if you still want to Get the UI, then we need to install a Desktop Environment like Gnome, etc.

#### If you need to install Gnome Desktop environment, you can do the below process and get the UI Display:

First you need to update packages, run the apt command or apt-get command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

You can search for desktop package using the apt command or apt-cache command:

```
apt search ubuntu-desktop
```

To install the Ubuntu desktop system (gnome 3), run:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

OR use transitional package name for Gnome 3 desktop:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

###### IF REQUIRED DIFFERENT DESKTOP ENVIRONMENT

Run the following to install Kubuntu Plasma Desktop/Netbook system (kde):

```
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
```

Want Lubuntu Desktop environment?, try:

```
sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop
```

Execute the following command to install Xubuntu desktop system:

```
sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop
```

#### GDM is a gnome desktop manager that allows to log in into your desktop. Check status with the following systemctl command to verify it is successfully installed:

```
systemctl status gdm
```

> After this process you can easily use `VNC` or `Remmina` or `RDP` or whatever tool you need to share the Dektop Display.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually did install the ubuntu desktop environment and used RDP for access. There is a black screen because the server is headless.